# PHP Write / Update Textfile, don't works if randomly Multiple Threads are try to update Textfile

Tags: php, python, multithreading, file, text

Here is my Code with filename 
it does work without problems if lets say i just use
update.php?pokemon=pikachu
it updates pikachu value in my found.txt +0.0001

But now my problem, when i have multiple threads running and randomly
2 threads are 
update.php?pokemon=pikachu
and
update.php?pokemon=zaptos

i see the found.txt file
is empty than!! 
so nothing is written in it then anymore.
So i guess its a bug when the php file is opened and another request is posted to the server.
How can i solve this problem this does accour often

found.txt

```
pikachu:2.2122
arktos:0
zaptos:0
lavados:9.2814
blabla:0
```

update.php

```
 <?php
    $file = "found.txt";
    $fh = fopen($file,'r+');
    $gotPokemon = $_GET['pokemon'];

    $users = '';

    while(!feof($fh)) {

        $user = explode(':',fgets($fh));
        $pokename = trim($user[0]);
        $infound = trim($user[1]);

        // check for empty indexes
        if (!empty($pokename)) {
            if ($pokename == $gotPokemon) {
                if ($gotPokemon == "Pikachu"){
                    $infound+=0.0001;
                }
                if ($gotPokemon == "Arktos"){
                    $infound+=0.0001;
                }
                if ($gotPokemon == "Zaptos"){
                    $infound+=0.0001;
                }
                if ($gotPokemon == "Lavados"){
                    $infound+=0.0001;
                }
            }

            $users .= $pokename . ':' . $infound;
            $users .= "\r\n";
         }
    }

    file_put_contents('found.txt', $users);

    fclose($fh); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an exclusive lock after open the file and then release the lock before closing the file:

For creating an exclusive lock over the file:

```
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
```

To delete it:

```
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
```

Anyway you will need to check if other threads hot already the lock, so the first idea coming up is to try a few attempts to get the lock and if it's not finally possible, to inform the user, throw an exception or whatever other action to avoid an infinite loop:

```
$fh = fopen("found.txt", "w+");
$attempts = 0;
do {
    $attempts++;
    if ($attempts > 5) {
        // throw exception or return response with http status code = 500
    }
    if ($attempts != 1) {
        sleep(1);
    }
} while (!flock($fh, LOCK_EX));

// rest of your code

file_put_contents('found.txt', $users);
flock($fh, LOCK_UN); // release the lock

fclose($fh);
```

**Update**
Probably the issue still remains because the reading part, so let's create also a shared lock before start reading and also let's simplify the code:

```
$file = "found.txt";
$fh = fopen($file,'r+');
$gotPokemon = $_GET['pokemon'];

$users = '';
$wouldblock = true;

// we add a shared lock for reading
$locked = flock($fh, LOCK_SH, $wouldblock); // it will wait if locked ($wouldblock = true)
while(!feof($fh)) {
    // your code inside while loop
}

// we add an exclusive lock for writing
flock($fh, LOCK_EX, $wouldblock);
file_put_contents('found.txt', $users);
flock($fh, LOCK_UN); // release the locks

fclose($fh);
```

Let's see if it works

Comment: tried it out, still happens the same after 1 hour i saw that the file is again empty

Comment: So in that case, I will use definitely a database or other kind of storage. The problem can be that 1 or more threads are opening the same file when another thread already opened and it still didn't close, so the result are unpredictable since the first thread will close the file when others are still accessing. You can use Mysql or even Sqlite as a database which manages pretty well concurrency. You can later export the results to another format like a CSV, Excel, etc if you need it

Comment: i work now with a database, but still it would be good to know how to solve this in this simple way because the lock does not solve the problem

Comment: @HumanKhoo I updated the code in the answer, take a look please

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort i changed my complete code for use it on mysql like you said running with database is better. 
But i tried your code out now for 20 minutes and it seems to not happen again till now

Comment: Great decision, IMHO it's better to use a database, because all those basic issues with concurrency are solved by default in a RDBS like MySql. Anyway, please let us know if finally  the concurrency issue with your files was solved when you test it for a while

Comment: And of course, if you finally find that my answer solved the issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks